# Generate List of methods of a class with method types

Tags: c#, class, methods

I want to generate a list of all methods in a class or in a directory of classes. I also need their return types. Outputting it to a textfile will do...Does anyone know of a tool, lug-in for VS or something which will do the task? Im using C# codes by the way and Visual Studio 2008 as IDE

Comment: Do you have source (.cs), or compiled assemblies? There is a huge difference...

Comment: [This](http://www.csharp-examples.net/get-method-names/) should do the trick. In short - you can get information about class and it's methods through process called [reflection](http://www.codersource.net/csharp_tutorial_reflection.html).

Comment: Directory of classes suggest that its code... that complicates the things a bit

Comment: no, it complicates things a lot ;-p

Comment: Sorry forgot to specify.....I was talking about .cs codes

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Sure - use Type.GetMethods(). You'll want to specify different binding flags to get non-public methods etc. This is a pretty crude but workable starting point:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ShowMethods(typeof(DateTime));
    }

    static void ShowMethods(Type type)
    {
        foreach (var method in type.GetMethods())
        {
            var parameters = method.GetParameters();
            var parameterDescriptions = string.Join
                (", ", method.GetParameters()
                             .Select(x => x.ParameterType + " " + x.Name)
                             .ToArray());

            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} ({2})",
                              method.ReturnType,
                              method.Name,
                              parameterDescriptions);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
System.DateTime Add (System.TimeSpan value)
System.DateTime AddDays (System.Double value)
System.DateTime AddHours (System.Double value)
System.DateTime AddMilliseconds (System.Double value)
System.DateTime AddMinutes (System.Double value)
System.DateTime AddMonths (System.Int32 months)
System.DateTime AddSeconds (System.Double value)
System.DateTime AddTicks (System.Int64 value)
System.DateTime AddYears (System.Int32 value)
System.Int32 Compare (System.DateTime t1, System.DateTime t2)
System.Int32 CompareTo (System.Object value)
System.Int32 CompareTo (System.DateTime value)
System.Int32 DaysInMonth (System.Int32 year, System.Int32 month)
```

(etc)

Comment: Out of interest, does that return all of the methods of the current type or it also include all of the public methods of its parent classes too?

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix: There's a very easy way to test it :) (I can't remember offhand myself, but it's easy to test...)

Comment: ok, I made a few test. I'm pretty sure it shows all the public methods. Though, there seems to be an attribute "DeclaringType" which seems to be the Type that declared the method. So if someone want to filter on a particular object in the hierarchy, it should be possible.

Answer (score 3):

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:/methods.txt"))
{
      foreach (MethodInfo item in typeof(MyType).GetMethods())
      {
            sw.WriteLine(item.Name);
      } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get at these lists very easily with reflection. e.g. with [`Type.GetMethods()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td205ybf.aspx)