# .NET C# - Is there a way to retrieve all available methods in a 3rd party COM assembly?

Tags: c#, .net

I currently have access to the COM object and some of its methods that I know of. I'm wondering if there is a way to list out all the available methods from it instead of me relying on someone else's documentation.

I'm building an application in .NET C#, and as you can tell by the question, I'm fairly new in this space. Some guidance will be **much** appreciated.

Comment: Please see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198417/generate-list-of-methods-of-a-class-with-method-types

Comment: There is a *very* strict separation between the interface and the implementation in a COM server.  You can only use what the author exposed in the type library with no back-door like Reflection.  What you see in Object Browser is all there is.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Visual Studio, you should be able to examine the COM object in Object Browser which can give you a visual of all the public members as well as private/protected if you want.  Object Browser availability depends on the edition of VS that you have though.

If you aren't using Visual Studio, you may be able to use something like [ILSpy](http://www.ilspy.net) or [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/). Otherwise, you can write code to print out the members using Reflection, as mentioned in the answer referenced by Koby above.

Comment: Thanks for responding. No, the Object Browser doesn't show any members in Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition. I completely forgot about ILSpy so will try that.

Comment: You may use also TLBIMP

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973800.aspx