# Showing all properties and methods belong to a class in C#.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, class

In C#, is there a way to show all the methods belong to a class?

Probably there is no inbuilt method to do this. But there should be a way to achieve this.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1198426/6741868) out.

Comment: I think you can do this using reflection, e.g. [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737151/how-to-get-the-list-of-properties-of-a-class)

Comment: @don-prog My link combined with yours completes the answer :)

Comment: @KeyurPATEL yep, true SO cooperation :)

Answer (score 0):

this will show you all the static and instanc methods for both public and private ones for class Program as an example, change the name of the class to the desired one

```
foreach (var method in typeof(Program).GetMethods(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance))
{
                Console.WriteLine(method.Name);
}
```