# Programmatically get a list of method names in a form

Tags: c#, winforms, methods, reflection

I would like to be able to get a list of names of all the methods in a form (similar to the list obtained by pressing Alt+M).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate List of methods of a class with method types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198417/generate-list-of-methods-of-a-class-with-method-types)

Comment: @Martheen The method ShowMethods(Type type) returns the names of all the members of the form. What I need is only the names of the methods, as I stated, something similar to the list obtained by pressing Alt+M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way to get only the names  of the methods created by me.

```cs
Type methodInfoType = (typeof(Form_CreateNodes));
// Get the public methods.
MethodInfo[] arrayOfPublicMethodsNames = methodInfoType.GetMethods(
    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);

// Get the nonpublic methods.
MethodInfo[] arrayOfNonpublicMethodsNames = methodInfoType.GetMethods(
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
```